# C: getopt(): option does not seem to have effect

Tags: c, getopt

I am trying out the following C code (saved in file called testgetopt.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void usage(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-d] -i input-TIFF-file -o output-raw-file\n", s);
    fprintf(stderr, "Note: -d indicates debugging option\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char c;
    size_t i;
    char *itext = NULL, *otext = NULL;
    FILE *fout;
    short debug = 0;

    if ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "di:o:")) == EOF) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "di:o:")) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'd':
            debug = 1;
            break;
        case 'i':
            itext = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            otext = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'i' || optopt == 'o')
                fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint (optopt))
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
            usage(argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Both -i and -o are needed\n");
            usage(argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("debug = %i\n", debug);
    if (debug) 
        printf ("input file = %s, output file = %s\n", itext, otext);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile using:

```
gcc testgetopt.c
```

But regardless of whether I include -d or not, I always get debug set at 0. The program should have -d set debug at 1, 0 otherwise.

What is being done wrong?

Here are the examples:

Let us first try with no -d

```
./a.out -i in.dat -o out.dat
debug = 0
```

Let us next try with -d included.

```
./a.out -d -i in.dat -o out.dat
debug = 0
```

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestions!

Comment: How did you try to debug? Printing out the results from `getopt` inside the loop would give you data on which to build a theory of what's going on, although kind stack-overflowers have generously done that work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `getopt` as a sanity check and then not using its result when it succeeds. That means the first option is always discarded. You can easily verify this by putting `-d` as a non-first option:

```
$ ./a.out -i in.dat -o out.dat -d
debug = 1
input file = (null), output file = out.dat
```

You can see that the `-d` did take effect this time but the first argument, `-i`, is not set.

There are several ways to fix this. The recommended way (IMHO) is to remove the first `getopt` call. Then change the sanity check to verify the actual options. That is, there should be code after the `getopt` loop which verifies that all mandatory options have been provided.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    char c;
    size_t i;
    char *itext = NULL, *otext = NULL;
    FILE *fout;
    short debug = 0;

    /* REMOVED THIS BLOCK OF CODE
    if ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "di:o:")) == EOF) {
        usage(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    */

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "di:o:")) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'd':
            debug = 1;
            break;
        case 'i':
            itext = optarg;
            break;
        case 'o':
            otext = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'i' || optopt == 'o')
                fprintf (stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint (optopt))
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option `-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf (stderr, "Unknown option character `\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
            usage(argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Both -i and -o are needed\n");
            usage(argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    /* ADD SOME ARGUMENT SANITY CHECKS */
    if (!itext || !otext) {
        printf("Missing mandatory arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("debug = %i\n", debug);
    if (debug) 
        printf ("input file = %s, output file = %s\n", itext, otext);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand "Then change the sanity check to verify the actual options. That is, there should be code after the getopt loop which verifies that all mandatory options have been provided." Could you please provide a reference/example? Thanks!

Comment: I have added an example code which removes the initial `getopt` check and adds some sanity checks after the command line parsing. The sanity checks are just an example and you may have different/other requirements to check.

Comment: Btw, why does the "default" not work? Here is what I get:

Comment: ./a.out -i tmp
Missing mandatory arguments
Usage: ./a.out [-d] -i input-TIFF-file -o output-raw-file
Note: -d indicates debugging option

Comment: Why does it not trigger the default message that both -i and -o are needed?

Comment: Why should it? Why would it ever hit the `default` case? There is only one option, `-i`, so the loop exits after parsing that one option. It will actually never hit the `default` case under any condition because `getopt` will either return one of the valid options or `'?'`.

Comment: I guess I do not understand what the "default" here means.

Comment: `default` in a `switch` is reached if none of the other `case` values are matched. The point is that your `case` statements already cover every single possibility that `getopt` can return and hence `default` will never result. (Not quite true as `getopt` can return some other characters under certain conditions but we can omit those details for this discussion).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117978/discussion-between-user3236841-and-kaylum).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `getopt` twice, you need to reset `optind = 1;` between the calls.

Comment: This works, thanks! But I would like to get to know how not to call it twice!

Comment: You are right, the real answer is not to call `getopt()` twice. @Kaylum's answer gives some good tips on how to do that

Comment: I can't seem to check both answers! Doing one takes away the check of the other! I will leave this comment in and check the other since that is more in the line of what I would like. Thx again!

Comment: You can only accept one answer. In this case @kaylum's is much more complete, so I'd accept that one.